# Filter and return dates with datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter, django-views

I'm on django 1.8 and i have a problem in filtering and return months from an object with date-time field and

here is my code :

```
Expense.objects.filter(is_done=True).dates('created_date','month',order='DESC')
```

The error is so confusing

```
'created_date' is a DateTimeField, not a DateField.
```

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: yea i did and updated the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`created_date` is a `DateTimeField`, not a `DateField`. You have to use **datetimes()** instead of **dates()**.

New code:

```
Expense.objects.filter(is_done=True).datetimes('created_date','month',order='DESC')
```